# How to select a range of columns in a case statement in proc SQL?

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have around 80 columns names diag1 to diag80. I am wondering how can I pick just 30 columns and apply a case statment in proc SqL. The following code produces an error because it doesn't understand the range.

```
proc sql;
  create table data_WANT as
  select *,
    case 
      when **diag1:diag30** in ('F00','G30','F01','F02','F03','F051') then 1
      else 0 
    end as p_nervoussystem
  from data_HAVE;
quit;
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Comment: not sure about SAS but in SQL server you have to make use of system tables if you want to select columns with certain rage dynamically

Comment: You cannot use variable lists with SQL.  Just use a normal SAS data step instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problem with that attempted syntax.  First is that variable lists are not supported by PROC SQL (since they are not supported by SQL syntax).  The second is there is no simple syntax to search N variables for a list of M strings.

You will need a loop of some kind.  It will be much easier in SAS code than in SQL.

For example you could make an array to reference your 30 variables than loop over the variables checking whether each one has a value in the list of values. You can stop checking once one is found.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array vars diag1-diag30;
  p_nervoussystem=0;
  do index=1 to dim(vars) while (not p_nervoussystem);
    p_nervoussystem = vars[index] in ('F00','G30','F01','F02','F03','F051');
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The inverse pattern to @Tom search for a nervous system diagnostic code:

- via `FINDW` over a concatenation of the observed diagnoses
- via `WHICHC` over an array of the observed diagnoses

````
data have;
  infile datalines missover;
  length id 8;
  array dx(30) $5;
  input id (dx1-dx50) (50*:$5.);
  datalines;
1 A00 B00 A12
2 F00 Z12 T45
3 A01 A02 B12 F00
4 Q12
5 Q13
6 T14
7 F44 F45 F46
8 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . G30
;


data want;

  length p_nervoussystem p_ns 4;

  set have;

  array dx dx:;
  array ns(6) $5 _temporary_ ('F00','G30','F01','F02','F03','F051');

  dx_catx = catx(' ', of dx(*));*  drop dx_catx;           * way 1;

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(ns) until(p_nervoussystem);
    p_nervoussystem = 0 < indexw(dx_catx, trim(ns(_n_)));  * way 1;
    p_ns = 0 < whichc(ns(_n_), of dx(*));                  * way 2;
  end;
run;```
````

Answer (score -1):

try it sys.tables and sys.columns and filter your columns.

SELECT * FROM sys.tables INNER JOIN sys.columns ON columns.object_id = tables.object_id